# How to toggle show white spaces in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

My keyboard fell down and I was left with this monstrosity:

[image]

How to toggle white spaces off? If that's what it is...

Current editor -> whites paces is already off

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was searching for a single space, and auto high lighting all spaces in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

View\Active Editor\Show WhiteSpaces
You can set on\off

Comment: thanks. Looks like it was turned off and still looks like this.